# Istio load balancer not working while application is running, pods are ok

Tags: amazon-eks, istio, istio-gateway

I have one application with multiple micro services which has exposed service type loadbalancer on port 443. On deployment on eks it generates a lb url which if I hit then it runs successfully.
Now I am try to do blue-green deployment with istio.
I installed istio. It created a load balancer in istio-system namespace. I did all setup of my application along with gateway and virtual service in some different namespace.
I used https 443 port in gateway manifest. All  eks instances are 'in-service' yet the istio loadbalancer does not work. I am clueless how to debug.
Seeking help.
I am attaching code as image, sorry for that.
[image]
[image]

if I run application with LoadBalancer without involving istio then it runs successfully, but istio's loadbalancer somehow not working. I am it lost here

Comment: Which Istio and Kubernetes version are you using? Could you please share a steps/tutorial that you used for blue-green deployment? Could you example yaml files for  you depoyment, gateway and virtual service etc.. ? Please make your [issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "All eks instances are 'in-service' yet the istio loadbalancer does not work." - could you please clarify what you mean? How do you know that LoadBalancer does not work? In which way are you testing it?

Comment: ec2 instances attached with loadbalancer are showing as 'in-service' from AWS load balancer page.
K8s version: v1.22.1
Istio:
client version: 1.12.1
control plane version: 1.12.1
data plane version: 1.12.1 (8 proxies)

Comment: Did you try to send request to the Istio ingress IP address? Could you do it? Could you share logs from the Istio ingress gateway pod (get pod name using `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` command and then `kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-{random} -n istio-system`)?

Comment: What kind of application does your deployment have? Could you share an example file of the deployment? Why are you using `protocol:TCP` in gateway - any specific reason - maybe the `HTTP` will be good for you? Why are you using port number `number: 30886` in the VirtualService?